# Protractor-typescript-cucumber framework: run mutiple baseUrl from command line

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am struggling with this issue I need to run typescript-protractor-cucumber based project on different-different baseUrl through command line I am not able to perform it. Could you please help me out with some info or link on the same github project. I am setting the baseUrl in config.ts file and trying to call them from hook.ts file using command line.

**Hook.ts & config.ts**

```
const { BeforeAll, After, AfterAll, Status } = require("cucumber");
import * as fs from "fs";
import { browser } from "protractor";
import { config } from '../config/config';
import { build$ } from "protractor/built/element";
let env = browser.params.environment;

BeforeAll({timeout: 100 * 1000}, async () => {
//await  browser.get(config.params.baseUrl.prod);
await browser.get(env);

});

After(async function(scenario) {
if (scenario.result.status === Status.PASSED) {
    // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
     const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
     this.attach(screenShot, "image/png");
}

import * as path from "path";
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
import { Reporter } from "../support/reporter";
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";

export const config: Config = {

seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",

SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
},

framework: "custom",
frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

specs: [
    "../../features/Search.feature",
],
 params:{
baseUrl:{
 prod:'https://www.abdec.com',
     test: 'https://www.facebook.com'
 }
},
onPrepare: () => {
    // switch(browser.params.baseUrl){
    //    case 'firsturl': browser.get("https://www.abdc.com")
    //    default: browser.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    // }
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12000);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
},

cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
    require: ["../../typeScript/stepdefinitions/*.js","../../typeScript/support/*.js"],
    strict: true,
    tags: "@SampleScenario",
},

onComplete: () => {
    Reporter.createHTMLReport();
},
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You can specify params in command line via `--params.key=value`, and obtain the passed-in params in script via `browser.params.key`.

**1) env.ts**

```
exports let config = {
    prod: {
        baseUrl: "https://www.asde.com",
        loginCred:
            {
                username: "asde.sin@ud.com.com",
                password: "asbcde"
            }        
    },

    test: {
        baseUrl: "https://www.facebook.com",
        loginCred: {
            username: "asde.sin12@ud.com",
            password: "asbcdefd"
        }
    }
};
```

**2) Cucumber hooks.ts**

```
const { BeforeAll, After, AfterAll, Status } = require("cucumber");
import { browser } from "protractor";
import { config } from '../config/env.ts';

BeforeAll({timeout: 100 * 1000}, async () => {
    let env = browser.params.env;
    // you need to put above line into this function, rather than
    // put at the top of import section, the hooks.ts will be loaded by
    // nodejs before browser instance inited. Otherwise, the `browser`
    // variable is null, it leads `browser.params.env` fail.

    await browser.get(config[env].baseUrl);
});
```

**3) Protractor config.ts**

```
export const config: Config = {

    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
    ...

    params: {   
        env: 'test'
    }
};
```

**4) specify env from command line**

```
protractor config.js --params.env=prod
```

**5) HomePageObject**

```
import { config } from './config/env.ts';
export class HomePageObject { 

    constructor(env: string) {
        this.env = browser.params.env;
        this.username = config[this.env].username;
        this.password = config[this.env].password;
    }

    login() {
        element(by.css('input.username')).sendKeys(this.username);
        element(by.css('input.password')).sendKeys(this.password);
        element(by.css('button.login')).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @yong. I am still facing issue with calling different property file with login credentials username and password  with respect to test environment. So If I am running the prod environment then load property value(username and password) or file for prod environment. Can you please help me with this. Please find below my property.json: `{"prod":"https://www.asde.com",
"prodlogin":
{"username": "asde.sin@ud.com.com",
 "password": "asbcde"
},
"test":"https://www.facebook.com",
 "testlogin":
 {
  "username": "asde.sin12@ud.com",
 "password": "asbcdefd" 
 }
}`

Comment: I am trying to set and call it from my page object class: `import {Value, Properties} from 'ts-json-properties';
Properties.initialize();
 export class HomePageObject{
   @Value('prodlogin.username')
   private username:string; 
   @Value('testlogin.username')
   private testusername:string;
   @Value('prod')
   private prodEnv:string; 
   @Value('test')
   private testEnv:string;
   constructor(){if(browser.baseUrl==this.prod)         
console.log('Doc =>', this.username);}else if (browser.baseUrl==this.testEnv){
     console.log('Doc =>', this.testusername);}`

Comment: I am still facing error on home page object and step definition class while creating object of HomepageObject.

Comment: I am still facing error on home page object and step definition class while creating object of HomepageObject.  Error on the HomepageObject class whcih states "Property 'env' does not exist on type 'HomePageObject'.ts(2339)"  even though I have imported the env.ts class. Error on the stepDefinition class while creating object of my page object class  "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
HomePageObjectStepDefinition.ts(15, 16): An argument for 'env' was not provided."

Comment: Please find both the class here below: **HomepageObject.ts and StepDefiniton.ts**:  `iimport { config } from '../config/env';
 export class HomePageObject{

   constructor(env: string) {
    this.env = browser.params.env;
    this.username = config[this.env].username;
    this.password = config[this.env].password;
}

login() {
    element(by.css('#email')).sendKeys(this.username);
    element(by.css('#pass')).sendKeys(this.password); element(by.css('#loginbutton')).click();`

Comment: Please find both the class here below:** StepDefiniton.ts**                                
`import { HomePageObject } from '../pages/HomePage';
import { config } from '../config/env';
const { Given, When, Then } = require("cucumber");
const chai = require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised"));
const expect = chai.expect;

const homePage: HomePageObject = new HomePageObject();


Given(/^that user navigates to (.*)$/, async (pages) => {
    homepage.login();
});`

Comment: Please help me out with this

Comment: @shivendrapratapSingh: Did you find any solution yet.?